# Showing image binary data using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to get the image stored in db as json and diplay  the image using javascipt. but not able to view the image. i tried fire bug to view the html code img src is showing null.

here is my php code to get the data from db table:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

include 'connect.php';

$b_id=$_GET['b_id'];
$c_id=$_GET['c_id'];

$sql_select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM business_directory WHERE business_category_id=$b_id") or die(mysql_error());

$records = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_select)>0){

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)){
    $records[] = $row;  
}
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
}else{

    echo 'data not selected';
}
?>
```

Here is javascript code:

```
function get_business(){

$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/ajax_practice/php/get_business.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,

        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var output="";
                    $(".gallery").append(output);

                        output+="<li>";

                        output+="<a href='category.html?b_id="+item.id+"' data-transition='slide' rel='external'>";
                        output+="<img src='"+item.business_icon+"'/>";
                        output+="<span>"+item.business_name+"</span";
                        output+="</a>";
                        output+="</li>";
                    $(".gallery").append(output);


            });
        }
    });
```

}

Can onyone help me that how can i get the data from database and show it using javascript.

Comment: You can't just put an img src at binary data (assuming that's what item.business_icon is). You will need to convert the data to an image somehow. Options may be, writing the image server side and setting the url of that image to the src of the image tag, or using canvas perhaps with the data url functions.

Comment: i don't want to use server side scripting, i want show it using javascript only

Comment: I just checked my json output and i found business_icon as null

Comment: Yup that will do it! :P We need to know what format your business_icon is, to provide the correct answer. How have you stored it?

Comment: i have stored it using php file_get_contents();

Answer (score 1):

You can't send it in binary format with json, so you can encode it as base64 string and send it as string. In client side you can use

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,base64Data" />
```

base64Data - base64 string coming from the server

You can see more info,

[Showing image data using javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201767/Load-Base64-Images-using-jQuery-and-MVC)

Comment: No, you can save it directly as binary or can convert it to base64 string and then can save it to database. But, base64 strings are very large strings, So, best way to save it binary. When you send it to client you can encode it as base64.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your image as base64 and use data url `data:image/png;base64,<DATA>`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: m getting image as null in json only

Comment: I just checked my json output and i found business_icon as null

Comment: @SheeshkamalVishwakarma try use base64_encode function in php `$row['business_icon'] = base64_encode($row['business_icon'])` in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the format of image stored in database. You say it is stored as json.

If it is base64 already, try this

```
output+="<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+item.business_icon+"'/>";
```

or if it is binary(raw image), try this

```
output+="<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+atob(item.business_icon)+"'/>";
```

To know what format it is just output `item.business_icon` on console if has strange characters, then it is binary form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
output +="<img style='width: 30px; width:50px;' src='data:image/png;base64,"+item.business_icon+"' />";
```